# Hibernate 4 - Commit issue with Oracle 10g and WebSphere 7

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g, websphere

I am using datasource to connect to Oracle database and insert data. 
Below is my hibernate config entry:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.datasource">jdbc/LOCAL_ORACLE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>   
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Below is the code snippet which saves the data.

```
final Configuration cfg = new Configuration().addResource("SampleTable.hbm.xml").configure();
final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
txn = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(cs90spTransDetails);
txn.commit();
```

The issue I am facing is when **txn.commit()** is called hibernate throws the below error:

```
[4/24/12 19:25:13:675 IST] 0000001a SystemErr     R Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection
[4/24/12 19:25:13:675 IST] 0000001a SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:116)
[4/24/12 19:25:13:675 IST] 0000001a SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:178)
[4/24/12 19:25:13:675 IST] 0000001a SystemErr     R     ... 13 more
[4/24/12 19:25:13:675 IST] 0000001a SystemErr     R Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: DSRA9350E: Operation Connection.commit is not allowed during a global transaction.
[4/24/12 19:25:13:675 IST] 0000001a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.commit(WSJdbcConnection.java:1064)
[4/24/12 19:25:13:675 IST] 0000001a SystemErr     R     at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:112)
```

NOTE: The above code works fine if I use **hibernate.connection.driver_class and hibernate.connection.url** to connect to database. Data gets stored in the database without any issues.

I am sure I am doing something wrong, which I am not able to figure out. Can someone tell me what I am missing.

Thank You.
Jay Chandran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see datasource obtained from the application server is configured to participate in [container-managed transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html).

Therefore you need to configure Hibernate to use these transactions (see [3.9.1. Transaction strategy configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional-transactionstrategy) and [3.9.3. Current Session context management with JTA](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-j2ee-currentsession)), and don't need to manage transactions manually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the property in the hibernate config. `<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup</property>` I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup.` I am not sure from where I can find this class.

Comment: Will I have to use a previous version of Hibernate rather than Hibernate 4?

Comment: @Jay: It looks like this configuration somehow changed in Hibernate 4, see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#d0e1022.

Comment: I downgraded Hibernate to 3.3.2 and used `<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup</property>` Now it works! Thanks for your help.